# JAVA : How to remove duplicates from list using stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I want to remove duplicates from a list based on a property(mail) of the items in the list.
I did this :

```
acteurs = acteurs.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The equals method of Acteur

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this.getMail().equals(((Acteur)o).getMail())) {
        return true;
    }
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Acteur acteur = (Acteur) o;
    if(acteur.id == null || id == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(id, acteur.id);
}
```

The equals method should be called during the instruction

```
acteurs = acteurs.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it isn't.
Where am I wrong?

UPDATE :
My solution :

```
List<Acteur> dto3s =acteurs.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Acteur:: getMail))),
                ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: That `equals` method doesn't compile. Show us the real one.

Comment: what should be the best method to remove duplicates acteur (who have same 'mail' value) then?

Comment: Also, your `equals` method can easily throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @thomas Have you overridden `hashCode()`?

Answer (score 2):

You broke `equals`/`hashCode` contract.

You need to implement `hashCode` according to requirements.

Comment: he is not using a Hasmap

Comment: so would hascode come into picture for List?? @talex

Comment: You can't tell from this piece of code.

Comment: @AdityaRewari `HashMap` used behind the scene in `distinct` method.

Comment: @RobAu You right, but it is good guess.

Comment: @talex which of the List implementation is using hashcode ?

Comment: @AdityaRewari None of them. The `Stream#distinct()` operation is currently implemented using a hash-based, unique-enforcing collection.

Comment: This is the correct answer IF OP has not overriden `hashCode()`

Comment: @Smile there no other explanation to this behaviour. Either hashCode not implemented or it implemented wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following solution, where you create a map by the distinct key `mail` and get the map's values

```
acteurs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getMail(), Function.identity(), (a1, a2) -> a1)).values();
```

the third arg `(a1, a2) -> a1` means that whenever it get a conflicts i.e need to add to the map an entry `(key,value)` with the same key it will use the map's current value, i.e no-op

> keep in mind, this will only compare by `mail` property, if you want to compare by a more complex way using the map logic, you might need to implement `hash()` and `equals()` properly

Answer (score 0):

Your equals method seems not correct because you need to "return false" if the "if condition" is not fulfilled

Comment: OP has updated the question. This answer is no longer relevant.